# Accessing multiple azure git repository in the same project with Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two Azure git repository within project. I need to access both repository in single pipeline. I mapped one repository with my pipeline.

As per document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#authorize-access-to-your-repositories

I am using command in pipeline `-script: git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" <clone URL>` to access another repository

got exception `: Mapping values are not allowed in this context."` due to colon (AUTHORIZATION:)

So tried escaping colon `-script: git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION':' bearer $(System.AccessToken)" <clone URL>`

but got error 
`Cloning into 'XXXX'...
fatal: unable to access <repository url>'`

I can clone this repository on local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below scripts,using literal blocks in yaml "**|**". Donot put the git command at the same line with `-script`,

```
- script: |
    git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" <repository url>
```